# Kafka ACL - LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: java, groovy, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have an issue producing messages to a Kafka topic (named `secure.topic`) secured with ACL. 
My Groovy-based producer throws this error:

```
Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9 : {secure.topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

Some notes about the configuration:

- 1 Kafka server, version 2.11_1.0.0 (both server and Java client libs)
- topic ACL is set to `All` (also tested with `--producer`) and the user is the full name specified in the certificate
- client auth enabled using self generated certificates

Additional server config:

```
 security.inter.broker.protocol = SSL
 ssl.client.auth = required
 authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
```

If I remove the `authorizer.class.name` property, then my client can produce messages (so, **no problem** with SSL and certificates).

Also, the kafka-authorizer.log produces the following message:

```
[2018-01-25 11:57:02,779] INFO Principal = User:CN= User,OU=XXX,O=XXX,L=XXX,ST=Unknown,C=X is Denied Operation = ClusterAction from host = 127.0.0.1 on resource = Cluster:kafka-cluster (kafka.authorizer.logger)
```

Any idea what can cause the `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` error when enabling ACL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the authorizer logs, it looks like the Authorizer denied `ClusterAction` on the `Cluster` resource.

If you check your topic status (for example using `kafka-topic.sh`), I'd expect to see it without a Leader (-1).

When enabling authorizations, they are applied to all Kafka API messages reaching your cluster including inter-broker messages like StopReplica, LeaderAndIsr, ControlledShutdown, etc. So it looks like you only added ACLs for your client but forgot to add the ACLs required for the brokers to function.

So you need to at least add an ACL granting `ClusterAction` on the `Cluster` resource for your broker's principals. IIRC that's the only required ACL for inter-broker messages.

Following that, your cluster should be able to correctly elect a leader for the partition enabling your client to produce.

Comment: Thanks. The topic's Leader is set to 0. I have tried to issue a Cluster ACL command `--cluster --add ClusterAction`, but no effect. I still get the same error.

Comment: Please, disregard my comment :) it actually works. It only started working after restarting the node. Thanks!